# Locate a 3D line given the spatial relationships with other known lines

Tags: computer-vision, geometry, robotics

I am trying to locate a 3D line with the spatial relationships with other known lines. I would like to formulate it as an optimization problem (or an alternative method), but I got stuck with it. Here is the problem statement. Suppose I have at least two known lines l1 and l2, and the target line is lt. I know some spatial relationships between each known line and the target line: 1) distance, 2）the position of perpendicular foot on the known line, and 3) the relative angle. Here is the graph illustration:

[image: locate a 3D line]

My question is:

1. Is there any similar problems and solutions I can refer to?
2. Do you have any suggestions on the 3D line representation (e.g., plucker coordinates)?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: For example, can you employ the way like following? (Weight of the constraints are significantly inequal.)
Line `lt` is determined by 2 points on the line.
Considering the circle {center is `P1` and radius is `d1`}, 1st point should be on this circle.
Similarly, 2nd point should be on another circle {`P2`, `d2`}.
Each point can move only along each circle, therefore degree of freedom of the optimization is only 2.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, fana. Yes, the weights of constraints are inequal, but I don't know how to determine the weights for the constraints. It seems like there are many alternatives to formulate the model. I found the relative angles can determine the direction of the target line. I will take your suggestion and the constraints of the line direction to see how to fit the target line.